# Moderator Pro-tem

Tags: discussion, moderation

we are looking in to getting at least one additional moderator at this site, to serve as a [moderator pro-tem](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/). What do the duties of a moderator include? To quote from the blog post, they:

> A Moderator is the site’s representative to the Network.
>
> - On a local level, they make sure their members have the means to work through local issues where they can.
> - They elicit help from us, and their moderator peers on the same site and within the network, as necessary.
> - If there’s a feature request for a specific site, it’s up to that community to vet the idea in their own meta. If the idea has merit, the Moderator would bring it to the Stack Exchange team.

Basically, they help to make the site flow. Time isn't a huge issue, for this site, it typically takes no more than a few minutes a few times a day to moderate the site.

What I would like to see is if anyone here has any nominations for new moderators. Moderators pro-tem can be nominated, but they ultimately are appointed by the SE staff. If we as a community nominate people who are qualified, however, then the SE staff has been known to appoint those very people. Feel free to nominate yourself as well, if you feel that you are qualified. Specifically we want people who:

> - Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
> - Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
> - Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
> - Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

If someone else has nominated you, please edit the response to indicate your approval/ disapproval of the nomination as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Alan Gilbertson](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/1286)

[image: Alan Gilbertson]

- Demonstrated experience in Graphic Design knowledge and theory
- [Visited constantly for 100 days](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/badges/23/fanatic?userid=1286) (Only 11 users earned this badge)
- Active in meta discussions

Comment: he is the superman

Comment: LOL! No, definitely not super. I just have the sponge nature: I soak up lots of stuff and give it back when gently squeezed.

Answer (score 4):

With Alan i would like to suggest name of :

## [DA01](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/306/da01)

[image: DA01]

---

## [Lauren-Ipsum](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/52/lauren-ipsum)

[image: DA01]

Comment: Either would be excellent choices, since they both have deep knowledge and plenty of experience with the SE sites.

Comment: we have 3 person here:P if they both have deep knowledge,you  have deep experience

Comment: Clearly I need to visit meta more often; I didn't know I was nominated. :) thank you, jack, but it's all Alan.